# MPI 3 shared memory and cache conflicts

Tags: mpi, shared-memory

When using MPI 3 shared memory, it occurred to me that writing to adjacent memory positions of a shared memory window simultaneously on different tasks seemingly does not work.

I guessed that MPI ignores possible cache conflicts and now my question is if that is correct and MPI indeed does not care about cache coherency, or if this is a quirk of the implementation, or if there is a completely different explanation to that behaviour?

This is a minimal example where, in Fortran, simultaneously writing to distinct addresses in a shared memory window causes a conflict (tested with intel MPI 2017, 2018, 2019 and GNU OpenMPI 3).

```
program testAlloc
use mpi
use, intrinsic :: ISO_C_BINDING, only: c_ptr, c_f_pointer
implicit none

integer :: ierr
integer :: window
integer(kind=MPI_Address_kind) :: wsize
type(c_ptr) :: baseptr
integer, pointer :: f_ptr
integer :: comm_rank

call MPI_Init(ierr)

! Each processor allocates one entry
wsize = 1
call MPI_WIN_ALLOCATE_SHARED(wsize,4,MPI_INFO_NULL,MPI_COMM_WORLD,baseptr,window,ierr)

! Convert to a fortran pointer
call c_f_pointer(baseptr, f_ptr)

! Now, assign some value simultaneously
f_ptr = 4

! For output, get the mpi rank
call mpi_comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, comm_rank, ierr)

! Output the assigned value - only one task reports 4, the others report junk
print *, "On task", comm_rank, "value is", f_ptr

call MPI_Win_free(window, ierr)
call MPI_Finalize(ierr)
end program
```

Curiously, the same program in C does seem to work as intended, which leads to the question if there is something wrong with the Fortran implementation, or the C program is just lucky (tested with the same MPI libraries)

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  // Allocate a single resource per task
  MPI_Aint wsize = 1;

  // Do a shared allocation
  int *resource;
  MPI_Win window;
  MPI_Win_allocate_shared(wsize, sizeof(int), MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &resource, &window);

  // For output clarification, get the mpi rank
  int comm_rank;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm_rank);

  // Assign some value
  *resource = 4;  

  // Tell us the value - this seems to work
  printf("On task %d the value is %d\n",comm_rank,*resource);

  MPI_Win_free(&window);
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: I am afraid your C program is incorrect. It should be `int *resource;` and then `*resource = 4;` and then `printf(..., *resource);`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Good catch, thanks. I updated the code. The behavior does not change, though, so my question remains the same.

Comment: You are not using the `baseptr` argument of `MPI_Win_allocate_shared()` correctly (correct usage might seem counter intuitive at first).

Comment: In Fortran what if you declare `integer, pointer :: f_ptr(:)` and set/print `f_ptr(1)`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet That produces the same result, but now I wonder if there is just something wrong with the example. Let me triple check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the MPI 3.1 standard (chapter 11.2.3 page 407)

> MPI_WIN_ALLOCATE_SHARED(size, disp_unit, info, comm, baseptr, win)
>
> IN size size of local window in bytes (non-negative integer)

Note the window size is in **bytes** and not in number of units.

So all you need is to use

```
wsize = 4
```

in Fortran (assuming your `INTEGER` size is indeed `4`) and

```
wsize = sizeof(int);
```

in `C`

FWIW

- even if the `C` version seems to give the expected result most of the time, it is also incorrect and I am able to evidence this by running under the program under a debugger.
- generally speaking, you might have to declare `volatile int * resource;` in `C` to prevent the compiler from performing some optimizations that might impact the behavior of your app (and this is not needed here).

Comment: The Fortran 2008 equivalent of C's `sizeof` is `STORAGE_SIZE` (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/STORAGE_005fSIZE.html).  That requires Fortran 2008.  GCC has the `SIZEOF` extension (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SIZEOF.html) and one can use `MPI_SIZEOF`, which we deprecated in MPI 4.0 (https://github.com/mpi-forum/mpi-issues/issues/51) because there is a Fortran 2008 alternative (which will be implemented by every relevant compiler before `MPI_SIZEOF` is deleted).